# How to Play video in another activity on clicking on button?

Tags: android, button, android-videoview

I have made two activity on first I have list of video list in cardview I want to play that video on other activity. I add videoview in 2nd activity, I don't want multiple activities for multiple videos. Hope you guys understand.

```
package eras.ppt.ras;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;

public class FYJCActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CardView mycard ;
    private Intent intent;
    private Intent intent1;
    private Intent intent2;
    private Intent intent3;
    private Intent intent4;
    private Intent intent5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fyjc);

        mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.physics);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
//                finish();
//                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
//                finish();
//                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
//                finish();
//                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview2);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
//                finish();
//                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview3);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
//                finish();
//                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview4);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent5 = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent5);
//                finish();
//                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my code I want to play a video on video activity.
I don't know how to play video on other activity that's why I didn't
add video link yet.

Comment: There is no question here, what is your question? Where is your code? There is almost no information here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add extra information in the intent with putExtra. For ex,

```
 mycard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.physics);
        mycard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FYJCActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("a_Tag","physics");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And in your VideoActivity, inside the onCreate method, you have to extract that information from the intent as follows:

```
String item_selected=getIntent().getStringExtra("a_Tag"); //same tag you used before
//now item_selected is "physics"
```

You can display the corresponding video based on `item_selected`'s value